# What is a passive web service?

Tags: web-services

Our company is studying the adoption of a new SaaS, but we'll have to integrate some resources into ou current application.
Talking to the SaaS company development support team they told us that the there is a webservice (SOAP) available but it is a 'passive web service', and that the connection to the software needs to be initiated to send or recieve datas.

We have a very short time to take a decision, and the support team is not available on weekends, so I came here to stackoverflow... and would like to know more about it, because I googled and coudn't find anything about the subject

Comment: Ask the company that's inventing new buzzwords what their new buzzwords mean.

Comment: You sure you googled? http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/WebServices/archives/0101/chandy/index.html ? Check the section - `Passive Web Services vs Active Web Services`. But, to be on the safer side, drop a mail to the support team to request them to expand more on the term. They may be using the term in a different context.

Comment: @verisimilitude I am in Brazil and some results may not show for me! But thanks for your contribuition :D And we can't wait for next Monday... the decision is to made up today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All web services are based on HTTP, which is a request/response protocol as written today.  If the SaaS consultant means that there's no push capability built into it, then s/he's correct.

A web service can certainly send data in response to a request, so that's not a problem.  It can receive any data you send to it, provided that you conform to the contract that the web service will publish.  But in both cases the conversation is initiated by a client that makes an HTTP connection to the web service.

The SaaS consultant is creating mystery where there shouldn't be any.  I think s/he smells cash, and you're going to be the source who will provide it.

It could also be that the consultant is being perfectly straightforward, but this is your first attempt to think about web services or service oriented architecture and you haven't the foggiest idea of what it's about.

You don't give any information on what you have to decide on or why that answer is unacceptable.  There's not a single use case or requirement to help someone here understand what your needs are.  I hope your understanding of the problem and requirements statements are better than this question.  If not, no wonder you're having issues.  Voting to close.